# Kubernetes for Windows networking - default CNI

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cni

Under this [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/), calico and flannel are not yet fully supported by windows.  I plan to use ToR (top of rack) static routing.

How do I install the default CNI?  (just do nothing?)

E.g. using flannel I will need to run - kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml

So what do I need to install for default CNI for ToR static routing?

Also a quick note, I'm using Kubeadm to set this up on-prem so any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there's a default CNI config [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/#windows-host-setup). It also shows you steps to set it up on a Windows hosts. And [this script](https://github.com/Microsoft/SDN/blob/master/Kubernetes/windows/start-kubelet.ps1)  would setup up the PodCidr that you'd need to run your kubelet.

You still need as you mentioned, setup your own ToR static routes.

Hope it helps!

Update from @JuniorPenguin:

> I would just add enable NIC promiscuous mode if you are using VMware

Comment: Your first link includes another link to setup the masters for installing CNI. But I am wondering if kubeadm/kubeadm config file would install the default CNI plugin.

Comment: Haven't tried kubeadm on Windows but essentially on Linux it install the more popular CNI plugins, but not the configs. The configs are generated when you install the overlay. In any case, you will have to configure networking on Windows.

Comment: It says in the official docs that kubeadm does not support kubenet -- does that mean it won't support the default CNI when working with kubeadm? Thanks!

Comment: That's my bet. kubenet has also been deprecated on the later Kubernetes version in favor of the overlays.

Comment: I found how to do kubeadm with kubenet -- its not under official docs but a work around -- [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34949)

Comment: For anyone reading this, I would just add enable NIC promiscuous mode if you are using VMware.  Thanks!